# Copy files in PowerShell too slow

Tags: powershell

Good day, all. New member here and relatively new to PowerShell so I'm having trouble figuring this one out. I have searched for 2 days now but haven't found anything that quite suits my needs.

I need to copy folders created on the current date to another location using mapped drives. These folders live under 5 other folders, based on language.

Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\Folder4\chs, enu, jpn, kor, tha

The folders to be copied all start with the same letters followed by numbers - abc123456789_111. With the following script, I don't need to worry about folder names because only the folder I need will have the current date.

The folders that the abc* folders live in have about 35k files and over 1500 folders each.

I have gotten all of this to work using Get-ChildItem but it is so slow that the developer could manually copy the files by the time the script completes. Here is my script:

```
GCI -Path $SrcPath -Recurse | 
Where {$_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).Date} |
    Copy -Destination  {
        if ($_.PSIsContainer) {
            Join-Path $DestPath $_.Parent.FullName.Substring($SrcPath.length)
        } else {
            Join-Path $DestPath $_.FullName.Substring($SrcPath.length)
        }
    } -Force -Recurse
```

(This only copies to one destination folder at the moment.)

I have also been looking into using `cmd /c dir` and `cmd /c forfiles` but haven't been able to work it out. Dir will list the folders but not by date. Forfiles has turned out to be pretty slow, too.

I'm not a developer but I'm trying to learn as much as possible. Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: How slow is it? 35000 files and browsing the folders *will* take some time. Hard disk have a physical read/write speed limit, and there is overhead for moving to different positions on the disk as well. This makes copying large numbers of files slow, especially when you copy them to the same physical disk.

Comment: Are the source and destination on the same computer, and are you running this from the source server, or from a workstation?

Comment: You have the `-Recurse` option on `Copy-Item`, but you're copying every item individually all the way down.  That means you're copying each folder recursively.  You're changing it from O(n) to at least O(n^2).  And your recursive copy is ignoring the date filter.

Comment: I should have included that the files are being copied from one server to another with the script being run on a jump server. It has drives mapped to each server.

Comment: Each folder that actually gets copied has around 190 files that are less than 500KB.

@GolezTrol - I didn't actually time it but a rough estimate was better than 15 minutes.

Comment: @Bacon Bits - Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Just a thought, but perhaps you should be running this in a remote session on the source server. This will speed up your GCI results considerably.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - Unfortunately, that is against policy, hence the need to run it from a jump server. I even have to wait for the developer to test because I cannot do it on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@BaconBits is right, you have a recurse on your copy-item as well as your getchild-item. This will cause a lot of extra pointless copies which are just overwrites due to your force parameter. Change your script to do a foreach loop and drop the recurse parameter from copy-item

```
GCI -Path $SrcPath -Recurse | 
Where {$_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).Date} | % {
    Copy -Destination  {
        if ($_.PSIsContainer) {
            Join-Path $DestPath $_.Parent.FullName.Substring($SrcPath.length)
        } else {
            Join-Path $DestPath $_.FullName.Substring($SrcPath.length)
        }
    } -Force
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Cole9350. I've modified the script and now have to wait for the developer to test it. I will post results back as soon as I get them.

Comment: Thanks everyone. @Cole9350, I accepted your answer as it did help. It's still slow but I believe it's because it's over the network and sheer number of files it has to search through.